# Is there a reason I get an API error in typescript but not python?

Tags: typescript, cookies, axios, cloudflare

I'm having a very unusual issue that no one has been able to solve. I'm on an M1 mac using Monterey.

We have typescript code that is supposed to hit an API (using axios). Whenever I try to run it (I mostly use VSCode but get the same result in Terminal), I get a Cloudflare security error saying I've been blocked, with not much context, just "The action you just performed triggered the security solution." One line in the error also says "Please enable cookies."

What is weird is that I can hit the API just fine using python, postman, or my browser. Additionally, my coworkers can pull the same typescript code off git and it works fine for them on Windows 10. The only failures are on my system, using typescript.

I have talked to the API provider, run it by everyone on my team, Googled everything I can think of, and asked ChatGPT and Google Gemini. No one has solved it. The API Provider did say it "was blocked with JA3 hash". Does anyone have any ideas of what might be going on? Any system settings that might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure why this is happening, but most likely it is because of the headers.

Try with withCredentials

```
axios.get(BASE_URL, { withCredentials: true });
```

or check the headers in postman and add in your axios request

Are your coworkers using another operating system?

Comment: That is not a solution anyone had suggested yet! Unfortunately, that is still not working. It did point me to some new avenues of research I'm checking out, but if you have other ideas, please share! My coworkers are all on Windows, good question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most useful answer, but this was solved. I sent the provider [this documentation](https://developers.cloudflare.com/bots/concepts/ja3-fingerprint/) and [this link](https://developers.cloudflare.com/waf/custom-rules/), and they confirmed it was a block on their side. They unblocked it, and now my code works as expected